# Want to use a for loop to find values that are equal and create a cell in between them

Tags: vba, excel

I want to compare two consecutive cells to each and if their value is the same, then I want to create an empty cell in between them. That is if `A1==B1`, then I want the program to right click and insert a cell in `B1` by shifting the value of `B1` to the right. I want to do this for every row I have. Unfortunately, I have limited knowledge in VBA and playing with the recording macro and looking online, I did the following

```
' dim is dimension
' allows us to declare variable names and their type
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
'.Row.Count (.Columns.Count) gives the index of rows (columns) used. If we don't use ., it will give us the end...
  For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
   For j = 1 To .Columns.Count
     If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j + 1).Value And Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value) Then ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j + 1).Select , Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
     End If
   Next j
  Next i
End With
```

However, Excel returns a Compile Error.

> End If without block If

I think my mistake lies in

```
Then ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j + 1).Select , Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to use `If`:

```
If condition Then doSomething
```

or

```
If condition Then
    doSomething
    doSomeThingElse
End If
```

Furthermore, if you want to combine multiple commands in one line, use a colon `:` to separate them. Commas are for separating parameters. In your case I would suggest to move the commands to separate lines to keep the code readable.

---

Next thing is that you shouldn't use `.Select`. In your case you can just replace

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j + 1).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

with

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Comment: beat me to it by seconds :)

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. It worked like a charm.